# Android Studio - Google Play Services error

Tags: android, android-studio, unzip

I'm having a problem launching my app.
I always had the Google Play Services in my app, in my gradle it says:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

But now, I don't know why, Android Studio is throwing an error saying:

```
Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task':app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices840Library'.
> Could not expand ZIP 'C:\Users\Roman\...\sdk\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\gms\play-services\8.4.0\play-services-8.4.0.aar'.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task':app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices840Library'.
...
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not expand ZIP 'C:\Users\Roman\...\sdk\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\gms\play-services\8.4.0\play-services-8.4.0.aar'.
...
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive
```

Seems like is tryng to unzip an .aar ... How I fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should also note that there's no point in having play-services-ads and play-services because that means every single one including ads. Include only specific play services that you need. This reduces apk size and the method count. [docs](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project)

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Android SDK Manager and make sure you have installed the "Google Repositories" and "Google Play Services" libraries. The error is caused by gradle not being able to find the necessary libraries to compile.

Comment: Already done, all is updated I checked personally in the sdk directory

Comment: Do you use the latest gradle wrapper and build tools?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that whenever we use google play services library in android, after compiling the library in build.gradle, we have to specify the library version in the android.manifest file under the application tag.

We do this via the `<meta-data>` tag. Note that directly entering the version is not a good practice, so we do it using the following way

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Having the same issue and it says that it cannot resolve @integer/google_play_services_version

Comment: try using your library in this way compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.+'

Comment: Also after doing this try to clean or rebuild your project. If google play services is properly installed via sdk manager then @integer/google_play_services_version would be found